# How to call multiple JSPs from one servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets, include

I have a Screen with 4 sections: Parm, Header, Detail and Footer.

This will be the workflow of the Screen: A user will input some data in Parm section of screen and click on Display button. Then the Header, Detail and Footer sections of the screen needs to be refreshed based on the selection in Parm section of screen.

So I have a JSP **Frm.jsp** which has 4 JSPs inside it (**Parm.jsp**, **Header.jsp**, **Detail.jsp**, **Footer.jsp**).

```
<body>
<iframe src="Parm.jsp" name="parmFrame"></iframe>
<iframe src="Header.jsp" name="headerFrame"></iframe>
<iframe src="Detail.jsp" name="detailFrame"></iframe>
<iframe src="Footer.jsp" name="footerFrame"></iframe>
</body>
```

**Parm.jsp** has a form with some input controls and has a button "Display" which on clicks submit the form to a Servlet **ScreenServlet**.

```
<form name="parmForm" action="ScreenServlet" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="criteria1">
<input type="text" name="criteria2">
<input type="hidden" name="section" value="parm">
<input type="submit" value="Display">
</form>
```

So the Servlet receive 1 request from Parm.jsp. Based on that request I can retrieve data for the 3 JSPs in that Servlet. But how can I call the other 3 JSPs (**Header.jsp**, **Detail.jsp**, **Footer.jsp**) from the Servlet? Confused.

Comment: Try with include JSP or Ajax

Comment: include JSP means JSP include directive like `<%@ include file="relative url" >`? If yes then how this will work in Servlet?

Answer (score 0):

**From Servlet call,**

**RequestDispatcher.include(request, response)**

For Ex,

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher1 = request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp1.jsp");
dispatcher.include( request, response ); 

RequestDispatcher dispatcher2 = request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp2.jsp");
dispatcher.include( request, response ); 

RequestDispatcher dispatcher3 = request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp3.jsp");
dispatcher.include( request, response ); 

RequestDispatcher dispatcher4 = request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp4.jsp");
dispatcher.include( request, response );
```

**But, I would suggest to forward to a single jsp and let the jsp include other jsps.**

For Ex,
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher1 = request.getRequestDispatcher("main.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward( request, response );

**In main.jsp**

```
<jsp:include file="jsp1.jsp"/>
<jsp:include file="jsp2.jsp"/>
<jsp:include file="jsp3.jsp"/>
<jsp:include file="jsp4.jsp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Home.jsp**

```
<body>
<iframe src="Parm.jsp" name="parmFrame"></iframe>
<iframe src="Header.jsp" name="headerFrame"></iframe>
<iframe src="Detail.jsp" name="detailFrame"></iframe>
<iframe src="Footer.jsp" name="footerFrame"></iframe>
</body>
```

**Parm.jsp**

```
<form name="parmForm" action="ScreenServlet" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="criteria1">
<input type="text" name="criteria2">
<input type="hidden" name="section" value="parm">
<input type="submit" value="Display">
</form>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ScreenServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.my.ScreenServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ScreenServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ScreenServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

**Servlet:**

```
package com.my;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class ScreenServlet extends HttpServlet {        

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {                      

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Home.jsp");      
        view.include(request, response);
    }                                                                               
}
```

**Header.jsp:**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

Header Page's Data
<%
    // Write your custom logic by checking the request paramter

   if (request.getParameter("criteria1")!=""){
   // do something as you are required.

   }
%>
```

**Detail.jsp:**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

Details Page's Data:
<%
    // Write your custom logic by checking the request paramter

   if (request.getParameter("criteria1")!=""){
   // do something as you are required.

   }
%>
```

**Footer.jsp:**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

Footer Page's Data:
<%
    // Write your custom logic by checking the request paramter

   if (request.getParameter("criteria1")!=""){
   // do something as you are required.

   }
%>
```